# How to transfer info to a method and then back to the main method for printing?

Tags: java, while-loop

I did this once before on a different project, but I have no idea how to do it on this project. I just need to do the calculations for my output in a separate method and then have them print to the console from the main method. I know that this is probably really easy for most of you but I just started coding yesterday, so I have never learned this.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // This allows for the use of the scanner in the class

public class SavingsAccount // Start of class
{
    public static void main(String[]args) // Start of main
    {
        double P; // These store the amounts that will be used in the accruing interest formula
        double i;
        double n;
        double S = 0;
        int timesLooped = 0;
        Scanner readConsole = new Scanner(System.in); // This is the scanner

        System.out.println("I am a savings account interest calculator."); // Prompts the user for input
        System.out.println("How much money have you deposited?");
        P = readConsole.nextDouble();
        S = P;
        System.out.println("Now, what is the annual interest rate? (i.e. .05)");
        i = readConsole.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Finally, how long do you plan on having the money in the account?");
        n = readConsole.nextDouble();
        while (timesLooped <= n)
        {
            S = S + (P * i);
            timesLooped += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Your balance in that time span is " + S + "."); // Tells you your ending balance
    }
}
```

Comment: The `return` keyword is a fundamental concept.

Comment: The exact description of what I'm trying to do is "do the calculations and conversions inside  separate methods. Pass the needed information into the method from the main method. After calculation is done, return the result into the main method for printing."

Comment: yeah I remember that from the other one, but I don't know how to use it on this project

Comment: Think about it. You pass parameters into a method, then return results or whatever to the callee.

Comment: I think I can figure it out but what do I call the new method?

Comment: If you started coding yesterday, then you should probably start with simpler things.

Comment: Whatever the function is. A method is essentially a procedure. If you have a procedure where you do a back flip, call it `backFlip`, `doBackFlip`, etc. I also recommend following conventions with camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static double doyourstuff(double d1,double d2,double d3)
{  
  write your entire logic here as above written in main method.
  return calculated_balance;
}


 public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     --read values via scanner as you read above.
    double S= doyourstuff(d1,d2,d3);
    System.out.println("Your balance in that time span is " + S + ".");-- your final call
  }
```